# Asp.net and JS Error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1564 in http://static.getjs.net/sd/1018/1012.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined

I get this error everytime I test a website in IE, no specific website. I changed one page on a site and it gave me this error. I first thought I did something wrong but then I rolled back the changes, but the error didnt go away, then I thought to test it in chrome, everything worked fine, then I tested other projects I made in IE I get this error in all my projects.

If I continue, the site still works until I go to a next page

Comment: This is common error when you try to find an element by id, (or other way) and not found on page.... and is null... where is your javascript code ? Now if this happens on all page, you have some kind of plugin that cause it.

Comment: Im not sure if it can be my javascript since no other of my projects now works in IE. but I noticed if I release the site and put on my IIS Server and then go to the site with IE everything works fine so I think there might be a problem with my local testing IIS (2 different pc's) awell ill just test in chrome or reinstall visual studio haha

Answer (score 1):

If it possible that you are missing a JSON polyfill for IE?

You have the line:
    `JSON.stringify(b)`

Before IE8, there wasn't support for `JSON.stringify(b)` and you had to load your own script to support that action.